# SSL on Android - trust anchor issue with my non-public trusted CA

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have my server which is running TLS encryption software. It is using a certificate signed by my own CA and during the SSL handshake it presents all intermediates CAs:

```
# openssl s_client -connect hostname:port -showcerts
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = serverEntity
   i:CN = My CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:CN = My CA
   i:CN = My CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I followed these two guides:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

and configured a custom CA as described here (I just added the CA cert in the PEM format): https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#ConfigCustom

I have also setup a KeyStore with my application certificates so it also validates itself to the server. On the other hand, when I try to establish the SSL handshake, I got the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I am a bit confused since non of the following root causes seem to be my case: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

This is the part of the Android application code. If I understand correctly, passing null as TrustManager (2nd parameter of sslContext.init) will use the default ones (also the one I specified in the network_security_config.xml)

```java
InputStream appInputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.appentity);
KeyStore keyStore;
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory;
SSLContext sslContext;

keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(caInputStream, "mypassword".toCharArray());

keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "mypassword".toCharArray());

sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket("IPv4-address", port);
sslSocket.startHandshake(); // <-- causes exception
```

network_security_config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Have you read the following? `In the case of PEM certificates, the file must not contain extra non-PEM data such as comments` https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#certificates Additionally I am not sure if multiple certificates in one file are allowed. E.g. for DER encoded certificate there is always just one certificate per file.

Comment: The problem was related to the network_security_config, I should have not used <domain-config> but just <base-config> as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#base-config